# How can I get the list of all users who didn't create or submit their sheets?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities

I am a new ASP.NET developer and I am trying to develop a scheduled method in the Global.asax file. This method will create a 
sheet for any user who forgot to create or submit sheet last week, and it will make the status of that sheet as a 'Pending'

I have the following tables:

```
Task Table: TaskId, Title
Sheet Table: SheetId, UserId, StatusId, WeekNum, Year
SheetEntry Table: SheetEntryId, SheetId, TaskId
Status Table: StatusId, Title
User Table: UserId, Name, GroupId
Group Table: GroupId, Name
```

For example, let us assume we have three users; John, Maria and Alvin. All of them are in the same group.

- John already submitted his sheet                     (status: Submitted)
- Maria created her sheet, but she didn't submit it        (status: Saved)
- Alvin forgot to create his sheets for the last two weeks

Then the result should look like something as following:

> users who submitted sheet = 1     ---> John
>
> users who did not submit sheet = 2    ---> Maria and Alvin
>
> users who did not create sheet = 1    ---> Alvin

Note there is a possibility that one of the users might not submit the sheet for more than one week. So the method should 
show a list of all non-created / non-submitted sheets for all the users in specific organization.

I am struggling now with returning the correct number of non-created / non-submitted sheets by all users in specific organization. **So how can I get the list of all users who didn't create or submit their sheet?** The list should include the userId, week and year of the sheet that he didn't create or submit.

Here's my code:

```
public void createPendingSheet()
{
        DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
        int currentWeekNum = SheetManager.getWeekNumber(currentDate);
        int currentYear = currentDate.Year;

        using (TestEntities dbContext = new TestEntities())
        {
            var listOfUsers = from user in dbContext.User
                             where user.GroupId == "Group3"
                             select new { user.UserId };



            var listOfSheets = from sheet in dbContext.Sheet
                                   where sheet.Year <= currentYear
                                   && sheet.Week <= currentWeekNum
                                   && sheet.StatusId != Constants.SHEET_SUBMITTED
                                   && sheet.StatusId != Constants.SHEET_APPROVED
                                   select new { sheet.UserId };


            //To show the list of users who didn't create their sheets
            var query = from u in listOfUsers
                        where !listOfSheets.Contains(u)
                        select new { u.UserId };


            if (query != null)
            {
                gvPendingSheets.DataSource = query.ToList();
                gvPendingSheets.DataBind();
                lblInfo.Text = "Number of users who didn't create their sheets: " + query.Count().ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                lblInfo.Text = "No Data";
            }
        }

}
```